# Number of unique figures in a grid with $n$ lines drawn without lifting the pen

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, planar-graphs

The problem is to find the number of distinct figures drawn from $n$ straight lines of fixed length in a grid, which I call snakes. Reflections and rotations of the snakes are identified, so the problem is to find the number of unique snakes. The snakes for $n = 1,2,3$ are illustrated below
[image]

Set $s(n)$ to be the number of unique figures with $n$ lines. I have found the first couple of values, but I couldn't find any pattern. I also couldn't see that it was mentioned in the [online encyclopedia of integer sequences](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C4%2C10%2C23&language=english&go=Search). My question is if there is any way to find a formula for $s(n)$? Maybe there are some other connections one could make, for example to graph theory (I think the problem is equivalent to finding the number of Eulerian planar graphs with $n$ edges, only cycles of even length and the number of neighbors of a node is less than 4). Below is table of values of the first few values

$$
\begin{array}{c|c} 
n & f(n) \\ \hline
1 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 2 \\ \hline
3 & 4 \\ \hline
4 & 10 \\ \hline
5 & 23
\end{array}$$

Comment: And if it's like in the game, snakes cannot overlap, right?

Comment: I think you have a miscount for $n=5$ and that the sequence you want is http://oeis.org/A001997